# Is using $ = jQuery; within jQuery( window ).on( 'load', function() { okay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As `$` is undefined in a `jQuery( window ).on( 'load', function() {` I use `$ = jQuery;` at the top of this code block and then I can use `$` rather than typing `jQuery` wherever I want to use it like this:

```
jQuery( window ).on( 'load', function() {

    $ = jQuery;
    var test123 = $( '#test123' );

});
```

However I have seen on some websites I use this code on it sometimes can throw a `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` message occasionally in the console.

Should I be using this method or is there a better alternative to use `$` over `jQuery`

Comment: Show the piece of code that makes `jQuery` available as a variable.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry I think I may have answered my own question now by trying to show you can example of this. It appears if I leave $ in the function() { part of the code it causes a $ is not a function error, as i've been copying the same code as document.ready type conditions, but it looks like that is the actual issue, so on a window on load $ is already available, it's just because I was mistakenly putting $ in the function() that it causes the error

Comment: There are multiple ways to avoid conflict/ errors when using `jQuery` and other possible `$` variables.  You should check them. [see jQuery Docs No Conflict at https://learn.jquery.com/](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside a try-catch.

```
try{
    window.$ = jQuery;
}catch(e){};
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var test123 = $('#test123');
});
```

Comment: Why could  `window.$ = jQuery` ever fail? Why would you only do it on `load`? `jQuery` is obviously available before the `load` event (otherwise `jQuery(window).on('load')` would not work). And typically when `jQuery` is available globally, then `$` will be, too. so overall, this code does nothing, but very elaborately. ;)